# Definition of int variable with value limits

Tags: c, integer

I'm new at C. I need to define an integer variable with a limited range of values.

In the specific case I need to define an int variable that can only assume the values from 0 to 5, so 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. No less, and no more.

What have I to add to `int var` to define it as described before? Or, is this the right way to define it?

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: You would have to write code that verifies the value before assigning it. The language will not help you.

Comment: The only way I see you can do it is when you are assigning a value to it you do an `if` that makes it to only take those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

C does not provide any facility to limit ranges of numeric variables - you will *have* to add your own runtime check for every assignment.

You can abstract out an assignment function that performs the check:

```
int ranged_assign( int *var, int newVal, int min, int max )
{
  int result = 0;
  if ( (result = (min <= newVal && newVal <= max) ) )
    *var = newVal;

  return result;
}
...
if ( !ranged_assign( &x, val, 0, 5 ) )
  // handle range error
```

Obviously, this won't work if you want to assign your ranged variable directly from input.  You'll have to read into a temporary, and then do the range check on that temporary:

```
if ( scanf( "%d", &tmp ) == 1 )
{
  if ( !ranged_assign( &x, tmp, 0, 5 ) )
    // handle range error
}
else
  // handle input error
```

You'll have to figure out your strategy for handling out-of-range assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would control boundaries in run-time, by checking the input and ensuring that it lies within the given limits. At compile-time, you cannot specify which values a plain int is allowed to hold.

An alternative is to use an enum, in which case only allowing certain specific values is actually possible. But enums should only be used if you actually need to give each index a unique name. Otherwise, using enums would only be obfuscation. Example:

```
typedef enum
{
  ZERO,
  ONE,
  TWO,
  THREE,
  FOUR,
  FIVE,
} number_t;
```

which is 100% equivalent to this:

```
typedef enum
{
  ZERO  = 0,
  ONE   = 1,
  TWO   = 2,
  THREE = 3,
  FOUR  = 4,
  FIVE  = 5,
} number_t;
```

A variable of `number_t` can now in theory only hold the values 0 to 5. This does however not prevent someone from assigning a garbage value to it, nor does it prevent bugs (or EMI) from modifying the contents of the variable. So the run-time checks mentioned above also serve a defensive programming purpose.

Answer (score -1):

```
int entredValue,inf,max;
printf("\nPlease enter inf value: \n");
scanf("%d", &inf);

printf("\nPlease enter max value: \n");
scanf("%d", &max);
do {
    printf("\nPlease enter a value: \n");
    scanf("%d", &entredValue);
}while (entredValue>max || entredValue< inf);
```